# RabbitMq RPC vs other sync methods

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, rpc, synchronous

#### Background

We have a system that consists of several microservices. For the notification events, we're using RabbitMq queues and exchanges. For sync requests, we are using HTTP/REST.

#### RabbitMQ RPC concern

We're would like to replace REST with **RabbitMq RPC**. After the initial happiness, we've checked [RabbitMQ RPC implemention](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) and it looks quite complex for a simple synchronous call.

[image]

#### Question

Is the overhead of **RabbitMQ RPC** okey? Do you recommend a better alternative? I like that unlike **gRPC**, with **RabbitMQ RPC** there's no need to maintain protobuf and then generate client and server libs.

Comment: So, in the end, did you choose to use RabbitMQ for your sync request-reply messages? We are considering using the same technique. Thanks

Comment: @Marco Hey, we did pick RabbitMQ. It turned out to be a good choice. RabbitMq is well predictable. Implementation and further maintenance were a breeze compared to gRPC. Especially because you control the format of the messages sent.  We used https://www.cloudamqp.com/ so that we don't have to bother with settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question, why you decided to move from HTTP/REST to RabbitMQ?

Comment: @marco For public API we are using HTTP/REST as it is easily documentable and in general way simpler to implement. RabbitMq/RPC is used for our microservices only. RabbitMq has less overhead size-wise.

Comment: So in the end why did you choose rabitmq rpc over REST?
What are the benefits? it seems much more complex and hard to debug for a sync request, where REST is much simpler to implement.

Comment: @Tomer Nowadays, we would use gRPC for RPC. RPC over RabbitMQ is quite okay in our case BUT as I advanced I see gRPC and protobuf as a solution that lets you focus more on the business logic. Who know I'll change my mind in the future. :D

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I started to work in a new company and they use RPC over rabbitmq, other than the benefit of queueing requests and load-balancing to the consumers, It seems quite complex to manage. 
Does waiting for the reply message from the consumer is done in a blocking manner, or non-blocking / async way?

Comment: @Tomer RPC over rabbitmq is also blocking.